# i cannot view the map, only google map area is shown

Tags: android, google-maps

i had implemented google map android api v2. though i can see the map area,, i had tried all the other sources.. !this is all what i can view as my output... please help..!

my MapActivity.java

```
package nav.android.app.navigationsystem;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

// Google Map
public GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

   try {
        Log.e("loading map. . . .","loading map. . . ");
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("catch. . .", "catch. . .");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  /* MapFunctionality mf = new MapFunctionality();
   mf.currentLoc();
   mf.addMarker();*/
}
/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
 // MapFunctionality mf = new MapFunctionality();
    Log.e("initializing map. . . ","initializing map. . ");
    if (googleMap == null) {
         googleMap= ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     // mf.currentLoc();
    //  mf.addMarker();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
```

}

my menifesto file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="nav.android.app.navigationsystem"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<permission 
    android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="nav.android.app.navigationsystem.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="nav.anoid.app.navigationsystem.MAPACTIVITY"/>

        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDi4EDHhxyY1-Tbpk2XN7ZbnSIqQ-7iIWo" />

    <activity
        android:name="nav.android.app.navigationsystem.StartingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_starting" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and my activity_map.xml file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check that google maps android API v2 is ON ???

Comment: First check your LOGCAT for warnings or errors from Google map API !!

Comment: it says google play store is missing... bt i had already installed the google play services for  api 19

Comment: also it says emulator without gpu emulation detected, bt i had checked the'use host gpu' in emulator option in avd edit dialog box....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nav.android.app.navigationsystem"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="nav.android.app.navigationsystem.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="nav.android.app.navigationsystem.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="nav.android.app.navigationsystem.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDi4EDHhxyY1-Tbpk2XN7ZbnSIqQ-7iIWo" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i had taken the key from google api console.. i had already given the sha1 fingerprint...

Answer (score 0):

Here is small check list

1. API Key
2. Package Name
3. Device having google play services upto date ([Availability](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context)))
4. Your keystore (Used to sign the app)

btw. You can remove MapsReceive permission